# How can I exclude certain files from being compiled in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I use different JS libraries in my TypeScript project.
I want TypeScript to handle those files as is, with no error checking.

How can I exclude certain files from compilation so I won't see errors from them?

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the process of migrating a ~100,000 line project to TypeScript and as part of the migration I wanted to just rename all .js file to .ts, introduce a build step and then commit the result.  This was so that I could add type information gradually, in the main development branch while regular development continued in the same files.  The idea was to reduce merge conflicts, and it worked really well (the ability to migrate in steps like this is one of the advantages of TS in my opinion).

I ended up adding an --ignoretypeerrors flag to the compiler:

https://github.com/turbulenz/typescript

Which doesn't print type errors, and makes the compiler exit with 0.  It does still catch syntax errors, though.  There is also a --failonerror flag in there which prevents the compiler outputting a .js file if the type checks fail (which can confuse some build systems).

I am not using the Visual Studio plugin, so this may not help you directly, but some people might find it valuable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio, you can change the build action of the typescript files you wish to exclude. Right click on file, then go to Properties, then change `Build Action` to none.

Comment: Thanks. Though the problem is with JS files. Their build action is none by default.

Comment: What does this suggestion apply to, some specific IDE?

Comment: I want to exclude typings folder from publish , but the items in the folder have build action as TypeScriptCompile , then what should I do ?

Comment: I haven't touched TypeScript in a while. Any new tools/projects introduced in Visual Studio 2017?